# Allow only keys from array and make it optional

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to learn TypeScript and here's the problem: I have exported the constant of `ROUTES`:

```
export const ROUTES: Array<string> = ["USD", "EUR", "PLN"];
```

And I want to create the `Rate` type. It should be the object with one or more keys that are in the `ROUTES` array.

```
const rate : Rate = { // Error
    USD: 1, // ALLOW
    PLN: 2, // ALLOW
    EUR: 12, // ALLOW
    BTC: 2222 // DENY
}
```

OR

```
const rate : Rate = { // No error
    USD: 1, // ALLOW
    EUR: 12 // ALLOW
}
```

What I've tried:

```
import { ROUTES }  from "../constants";

type Rate = {
    [K in typeof ROUTES[number]]: number
}
```

AND

```
import { ROUTES }  from "../constants";

const allowedKeys1 = [...ROUTES] as const;
const allowedKeys2 = ["USD", "EUR", "PLN"] as const;

type Rate = {
    [K in typeof allowedKeys[1 | 2][number]]: number
}
```

Notice that `allowedKeys2`  and `allowedKeys2` are different and give diffenet effects. `allowedKeys1` does nothing and `allowedKeys2` forces to use **all** keys, but doesn't use imported array. Using directly `ROUTES` is the same as using `allowedKeys1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to already know that `as const` plays a role here. Without `as const`, the information about specific array elements is lost at assignment.

Now you can use a simple partial `Record` type.

```
export const ROUTES = ["USD", "EUR", "PLN"] as const;

type Rate = Partial<Record<typeof ROUTES[number], number>>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=59&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wEoHkCqAVAUQGU4BeOAbQCIciARKgGjioJwyZYAUAZAOSoBdOAENUiFOgDcAKBkwAnmGBwMImCvJcRsAJYiANgB4MwJFAAmRxcogAzVbkJEKyAK4BbAEbAog5u7evgB8wXJIaPBQ6ioAXKoxZHAA3nAA9GlwBFBQ0DJwBXC0dPEAjMwZcACCPDxYAOr5hbx88QBMFZk1dY2FWexlHeldtQ1NBQBCeADC7W3zw3B0BHwAmjIAvuGSUTFtcPFqGkmplXwQcL65UONF9GWd1aO9hWwYg4vdYxtAA)

Comment: Oh, God, Thank you! Yes, I knew that `as const` plays a role, but I didn't realize what exact role.